# JS / Node.js string().replace() help also help editing URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to edit a string in Node.js. I am developing a web proxy, and I need to rewrite some stuff.

What I need to rewrite is when there is two querystrings in a URL.
I just need the first one to stay but the rest to be modified to "&".
This is what I got.

```
.replace(new RegExp(/src="(.*?)?(.*?)?&_get=/gi),'src="$1' + '$2' + '&_get=')
```

But it's not replacing the querystring but the replace is working.

I also need this in string.replace() specifically. If this is not possible, I would like to know how I can get a URL to redirect to a link that replaces the querystring except the first one.

Comment: Replaces in the sense, just removes the rest of the query params?

Comment: I just need only the first querystring and the rest to be replaced with "&".

Comment: Could you add some sample input and output to your question, I'm not super clear on what you're expecting.

Comment: I want this to replace ```src="balalala?query?_get=https://example.org``` into this ```src="balalala?query&_get=https://example.org```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input output example in the comments, it seems like there's lots of ways you could do this.

One way would be to find the index of the last "?" and use the substring method to "replace" it.

```
let str = "balalala?query?_get=https://example.org"

let ind = str.lastIndexOf("?")

let newStr = str.substring(0,ind) + "&" + str.substring(ind+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `balalala?` is always going to be constant, you can separate that out.

```js
var source = 'balalala?'
var str = 'balalala?query?_get=https://example.org'
var rest = str.replace(source, '');

console.log(`${source}${rest.split('?').join('&')}`);
```